# Why is code below causing TypeError in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import "../../shared" as Examples

Item{
  Slider {
    x: 0;
    y: 0;        
    id: minSizeSlider;
    value: 5.0;
    minimumValue: 0.0;
    maximumValue: 128.0
    onValueChanged: {
        if( value < maxSizeSlider.value ) {
            console.log("minValue:" + value);
        } else {
            value = maxSizeSlider.value;
        }
    }
}

Slider {
    x:0;
    y:100;        
    id: maxSizeSlider;
    value: 50.0;
    minimumValue: 0.0;
    maximumValue: 128.0
    onValueChanged: {
        if( value > minSizeSlider.value ) {
            console.log("maxValue:" + value);
        } else {
            value = minSizeSlider.value;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this I receive:

```
example.qml:54: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
```

It looks like the line:

```
if( value < maxSizeSlider.value )
```

is the problem, especially

```
maxSizeSlider.value
```

appears to cause the error.
The example works as expected, the only problem is the error output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first `Slider`is initialized, `onValueChanged` fires immediately because you're setting a value (5.0) different from the default value (0). At that time, the second `Slider` is not yet loaded, so you can't access its value.
You can get rid of the error by excluding that case:

```
Slider {
    x: 0;
    y: 0;        
    id: minSizeSlider;
    property real defaultVal: 5.0
    value: defaultVal;
    minimumValue: 0.0;
    maximumValue: 128.0
    onValueChanged: {
        if( value == defaultVal ) { // <== default value, no need to check
            return; 
        }
        if( value < maxSizeSlider.value ) {
            console.log("minValue:" + value);
        } else {
            value = maxSizeSlider.value;
        }
    }
}
```